# Can I block specific apps from using GPS?

Tags: gps, privacy

I like to leave GPS enabled so that it's ready to go when I open Maps or certain other location based apps.

However, one app that I don't want to access GPS is Facebook. There is, as far as I can tell, no option within the Facebook app to prevent it from trying to access GPS whenever it starts.

Is there another app or setting I can use which will allow me to leave my GPS enabled, but block specific apps, like Facebook, from accessing it?

***Note:*** I took a look at [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-to-make-certain-apps-turn-on-gps-automatically), which suggested using [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to essentially *[whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist)* certain apps. I have Tasker installed, but I can't get it to do what I want, which is essentially *[blacklist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist)* specific apps.

***Note 2:*** My phone is not rooted, and I hope to find a solution that does not require rooting.

***Note 3:*** I have Android 2.3.6

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think you'll find a solution without being rooted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With LBE Privacy Guard you can block positioning permissions for certain apps.
You can download it here: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite

It is important to note that LBE *does* require your phone to be rooted.

Comment: Also an app called "Permissions" does something similar on rooted devices. However, keep in mind that such utilities may cause apps you deny permissions to crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, LBE Privacy Guard requires a rooted phone, and mine is not rooted. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible without rooting. Willing to be proven wrong though!

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is an old question for Android 2.3.6, but changes in the Android OS relating to this question are worth mentioning.

The new permissions model in Marshmallow (Android 6.0) allows you to block specific applications from using location services (which includes GPS) without rooting.

Go to Settings->Apps->"Specific App Name"->Permissions. There is a toggle switch for "Location", which you can use to stop the specific app from using location services.